# Bag combo for a field recorder/mixer 

Tags: field-recording, kit-bag, mixer

I'm looking into buying a Fostex FR2-LE and already have a Sound Devices MixPre. Does anyone know of a bag that would hold both the recorder and mixer? I looked at porta brace but couldn't find what I was looking for. Ric Viers suggests the Porta brace AR-FR2 in the *Sound Effects Bible* but I don't think that will hold the mixer too. What would you guys suggest? Thanks.

Comment: I have the AR-FR2 and it holds a FR2, a MixPre, my Neumann 191 Matrix box, and I still have room for external batteries for the FR2.  It has 3 pockets.

Answer (score 2):

This is a Petrol Bag, model PS607 (http://www.petrolbags.com/Sound?q=node/1168).  It fits my FR_2LE and mixpre quite well with lots of room for cabling and a few extras.  I have to have another bag to haul around the mics and other needed stuff but it it is great for recording as a shoulder bag.  If you are jumping into the menus in the FR-2LE a lot, it might get annoying as the front is not super easy to access once you have it over your shoulder.  I find I tend to do the menu settings at the start and then don't touch them much.  You still have full access to the gain and input levels and the meters along the spine so that is all accessible via this set up.

Answer (score 0):

Look at Petrol and Portabrace bags.  They both offer a really wide range of bags for all the field gear on the market.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest using a camera bag.  Depending on how much kit I am carrying I use different Lowepro bags.  I use a sling bag when I need to walk with the recorder and ruck sacks when I know that I will be stationary.  I just vary the bag size according to the number of mics I need to carry.  Camera bags have the advantage that they have extra straps for a tripod which can either be used for the boom pole or a small lighting stand.

http://products.lowepro.com/product/Classified-Sling-220-AW,2141,23.htm